# Matlab: Import multiple data sets from one text file

Tags: matlab, import, octave

So I've got a script that parses some data for me in a different environment and I'm outputting those data to file, which I'd later like to read in to MATLAB. However, if I write, say, 10 data sets into the same file (the ideal situation), MATLAB will just read the first one in. Ideally, I'd like to to read in a cell array of structs containing the results of the import. I have some leeway with how I output the files, but basically it has to be something simple that I can write one line at a time.

Unfortunately it would be very difficult to just append additional data sets as columns. Here's an example of some sample data:

```
DataSet1
x   y   z
3.82724 60.8234 13.0031
3.79987 60.909  -8.89291
3.75338 60.9124 19.5031
3.67715 61.0104 -24.5894
3.68124 61.0889 -20.8511
3.88438 61.1817 34.891
3.71405 61.2379 16.31
3.85504 61.245  -19.3778
4.09736 68.85   5.86954
3.39505 69.9457 64.8669
3.36033 69.9552 -58.8838
3.39427 70.9253 -26.0232
3.35769 70.9523 18.7863

DataSet2
x   y   z
3.73244 60.597  -21.6651
3.81217 60.712  -29.5505
3.74396 60.7554 -43.6225
3.70079 60.8271 -69.0996
3.87417 60.8662 -49.8068
3.74371 61.6553 34.915
3.815   61.7063 28.5842
3.88035 61.802  78.4314
```

Ideally I'd like to keep this sort of structure. The best alternatives I see are to write to tons of different files (not ideal), or to write it to one long array and then have some header information in there indicating where each dataset starts. Again, not an ideal situation. Is there any way to use something similar to importdata()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the text reading/import routines that come with Matlab assume there's 1 dataset per file. Possibly with some header lines or some random missing values or blank lines, but that's about it for their flexibility.

If you want to import these datasets, you'll have to write your own routine which uses `fgetl` in a loop, interprets and parses each individual line and appends it in a (possibly new) cell array.

The question becomes: is the time you spend writing that routine worth getting rid of the "ugliness" of multiple files, 1 for each dataset?

Comment: Yeah, I actually ended up just writing the data as *shudder* an XML file, because I could easily parse it into structs, and now it's done. Not the ideal situation but it worked for the quick-and-dirty.

Accepting this answer for posterity, as the answer to the question in fact is that what I originally wanted to do is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use textscan. It is very flexible, so I am sure you can adapt it to your case. Here is the code for your example data set:

```
C = textscan(fd, '%f%f%f', 'TreatAsEmpty', {'x y z', 'Dataset1', 'Dataset2'});
```

C is a cell of 3 column vectors with double values, one for every %f.

```
>> C{1}

ans =

   NaN
   NaN
3.8272
3.7999
3.7534
....
```

As you see, you will get NaN in places where you have dataset separators, so you can easily split your datasets. The 'string' dataset separators have to be specified  explicitly as TreatAsEmpty parameter (I have changed the 'x y z' string here to include one space between the characters).

Comment: The main problem I have with this is that I'd prefer it if they were actually parsed as separate datasets (i.e. the headers are read in and used to build a struct or something). If I'm going to do it this way, I could just skip the headers for each dataset and replace dividers with a line like -1i -1i -1i or something distinct.

Comment: @Paul sure. But then you can also do anything you like with the data you save, including saving it in hdf5 format and use load to load the data arranged to your liking. I thought the question was how to nicely and easily read what you have. It turned out to be in fact what is a good way to save data so that you could read it in matlab into a data structure you have in mind. I guess I missed the point. In that case I would suggest instead of using XML, write complete hdf5 file.

Comment: Well, it's already done, so no matter. I thought I was more specific that I want to retain the headers so I can tell the data apart. While HDF5 might be better than XML, XML is very, very easy to code in by hand and to read out, whereas with HDF5 I'd need to import a library and my primary goal was minimizing the amount of futzing around with the data output (the API and IDE I was forced to use were nightmarish). No matter, I still voted for this answer because I think it's a very good answer to someone looking to do something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to break away from the shackles of text-based data if you can.

If you are using Matlab to generate your data, then you have a few easy options.  For example, you can use the `save` command with the `-append` flag to add variables to your file.

```
save('someFileName.mat', 'Dataset1');  %Create a file with one variable
% ... do more work
save('someFileName.mat', 'Dataset1', '-append');  %Add another variable to the dataset
```

You can also (as of 2012a) use the `matfile` class to manipulate individual variables, for example

```
interfaceToFile = matfile('someFileName.mat','writable',true);
interfaceToFile.datasets = cell(100,1);
interfaceToFile.datasets(1,1) = {dataset1}; 
interfaceToFile.datasets(2,1) = {dataset2};
```

If you are using some other method to generate your data, I would look into the HDF5 format.  It was developed to be used with C and Fortran programs, and has an efficient Matlab interface, as well as implementations in many other languages.

If you need text, then one of the other answers is probably sufficient.

Comment: If it were anything more serious I'd use a simple binary serialization format to write the files and read them out myself. Also, I'm clearly not using MATLAB to generate them, otherwise I wouldn't have to bother importing them.